# Apply SceneKit shader modifier on multiple nodes

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit

The question:
Is there a way to apply Shader Modifiers not just to a specific `SCNMaterial` or `SCNGeometry` (as these are the only classes adopting `SCNShadable` protocol) but to a set of `SCNNodes`, for example to all child nodes of a selected one?

Problem I am trying to resolve:
I have shader code, which clips (`discard`s fragments) geometry by calculations over uniform parameters. In fact it can clip model by axis coordinates or random "box" volumes passed as uniform.

I didn't find any information about clipping model in `SceneKit` so I decided to stick with shaders. Applying Shader Modifier to every node seems incorrect. However it did work on simulator but it doesn't work on a real device, since it exceeds resource limit. I also tried `SCNTechnique` but what I've found looks like it is suited for post-processing rather than handling fragments rendering.

Applying Shader Modifier to scene's `rootNode` would be a way to go IMHO, but I am not sure if it is even possible. 
Did I miss something about using shaders in SceneKit? Or there are better ways to perform parametric geometry clipping?

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact use case, so I don't know how suitable this is, but have you explored rendering the geometry without SceneKit, using pure Metal? You could do this kind of clipping in a vertex shader (have a boolean 'discarded' field on your VertexOut struct, set to true when clipping with a volume, and discard the fragment when that field is set to true).

Comment: Application heavily relies on SceneKit, so it is not possible to abandon it. Also, I don't understand suggestion with processing clipping in vertex shader, instead of fragment because in this case it will discard whole polygon if it was clipped mid-vertex, which is not nice. What is the trick with vertex shader clipping?

Comment: What do you mean by « However it did work on simulator but it doesn't work on a real device, since it exceeds resource limit » ?

Comment: When I try to apply a shader modifier to each geometry object on a scene, the app on real device crashes with message: `Exceeded HW limit of resources used by render encoder working in Memoryless mode.` I found little about "Memoryless mode" but it seems that there are simply too many shader modifiers for a device to handle (also because applying less amount does work). It also does work on simulator.